# How to measure network traffic usage?

Tags: networking

I want to know how much bandwidth my server is using. How much in, how much out. How do I know that?

I think there is a software, netstat or something that took care that sort of thing.

Comment: Do you want to know what it's currently using or do you want historical usage too ?

Comment: Try speedtest.net.
It will give you all your required details

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/257263/how-to-display-network-traffic-in-the-terminal

Answer (score 6):

RRDTool and/or mrtg will do the trick. It stores the tx and rx counters of an interface (or any other metric you wish to provide) in a database and creates nice graphs of it.

[image]

Been using it for for years..

http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

Comment: It's also worth mentioning [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) to make management/generation of MRTG graphs easier.

Comment: And also [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). A list of applications using RRD is available here: http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/rrdworld/index.en.html.

Answer (score 2):

I use `iftop` for a quick view of current bandwidth usage.

`iftop` can show you the current connections (IP addresses and ports) as well as the current bandwidth that each connection is using.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find out how much data has been transmitted over an interface is to issue `ifconfig` this will list all devices with RX and TX bytes since starting the device.

For an overview of the current bandwidth i recommend `bwm-ng`.

For a long term observation `cacti` is the tool of my choice.

Answer (score 1):

Another real-time network statistic tool I use on the command-line is [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/shots/iptraf-dstat1.gif). It shows data like current bandwith, open connections and transmitted packets.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at using this package, `vnStat` which purports to do what you want using the same data that you're looking at from `ifconfig`.

- http://humdi.net/vnstat/

*excerpt of features*

> - quick and simple to install and get running
> - gathered statistics persists through system reboots
> - can monitor multiple interfaces at the same time
> - several output options
>
>   - summary, hourly, daily, monthly, weekly, top 10 days
>   - optional png image output (using libgd)
> - months can be configured to follow billing period
> - light, minimal resource usage
> - same low cpu usage regardless of traffic
> - can be used without root permissions
> - [online color configuration editor](http://humdi.net/vnstat/coloredit/)

#### Example

[image: ss #1]

#### ifconfig

If you're only interested in the amount of traffic that came in (RX) and the amount of traffic that went out (TX) you can get this a variety of ways, but the easiest is to look at the output of `ifconfig`.

#### Example

```
$ ifconfig wlp3s0
wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.20  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::226:c7ff:fe85:a720  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:26:c7:85:a7:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15846640  bytes 9655221715 (8.9 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15902606  bytes 3655307055 (3.4 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

In the above output you'll notice the amount of bytes that my WiFi network device has received (RX) and sent (TX).